# Rails devise is loging out after my method calling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have such metod in secret controller(also i use carrierwave):

```
def create
    @secret = Secret.new
    @secret.file_to_solve = params[:file]
    @secret.file_type = "audio" if audio(params[:file])
    @secret.file_type = "image" if image(params[:file])
    @secret.name = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params[:file].original_filename)
    @secret.status = "uploaded"
    @secret.save!
    render :layout => 'solving_layout'
  end
```

after when i call this method with such php script, to send file to server:

```
<form method="post" action="http://192.168.1.4:3000/secrets" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="post">
Ключ от учетной записи:
<input type="text" name="key" value="d759cb7a0bc6f5433ccdb790cd5bc63b">
Файл капчи:
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="загрузить и получить ID">
</form>
```

i see that my devise session is destroyed, but why? What i do wrong? I must log in once again(

My route is:

```
get "users/cabinet"

  get "users/solving"

  devise_for :users

  #resources :sessions


  resources :secrets

  match "users/solving" => "users#solving", :as => :user_solving
  match "users/cabinet" => "users#cabinet", :as => :user_cabinet
```

in user controller i didn't have any devise logic of signing in, just this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :auth_user

  def auth_user
    redirect_to new_user_session_path unless user_signed_in?
  end

  def cabinet
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end

  def solving

  end


end
```

I can't understand what i do wrong? Why is my devise session destroyed, and how to solve it? In log's i didn't see anything strange...

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'i see that my devise session is destroyed'? what indicates that exactly? why do you use a php script?

Comment: @phoet becouse i need to upload to server, from other php script. Session is destroyed, becouse i see that i must sign in again

Comment: @phoet maybe this becouse i'm sending new object from non rails server, and some problems with csrf?

Comment: seems that skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token help